# why content goes outside the modal body

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

My content goes outside the `<div class="modal-body">` only in chrome browser.

```
<div class="container">  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Heading</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body ModalBodyColor">asdsadsddsadsdsdj4k3bekbdd2k4.......</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

click on button open modal then modal content goes out. Below is the link for jsfiddle

click: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Akkikumar77/brLky3jL/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the [`word-wrap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap) property (assuming the text is one long word):

```
.modal-body p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanchitpatiyal95/brLky3jL/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Because of you are typing single line words without having spaces in between them. 
You need to break them or use if this is some type of code u may use

```
p{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

or you can use

```
p{
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: overflow auto will add the slider which does not look good hence using word-wrap is good choice